# Any way to make a Separator within a WPF menu more narrow?

Tags: wpf, menu, separator

I've noticed that the margin or height of the default Separator as it is styled in the menus in WPF seems to be slightly larger than some other applications such as Visual Studio 2010. I know that these Separators can be re-templated by applying a new style with a custom ControlTemplate but like always I'm looking for any possible way to change this without having to manually re-define the composition of the control.

If what I'm asking for isn't possible I will accept an answer if somebody can provide an authoritative and exhaustive explanation. Also I would like to stress that I'm not interested in a lecture about how to redefine the ControlTemplate as I'm treating that as the last resort and I'm already aware of how to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? It is annoying me too.

Comment: Not yet, I'll be sure to update my post if I do however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The style for the aero.normalcolor MenuItem Separator looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="0,6,0,4">
                    <Rectangle Height="1"
                               Margin="30,0,1,1"
                               Fill="#E0E0E0"/>
                    <Rectangle Height="1"
                               Margin="30,1,1,0"
                               Fill="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You would need to copy this style to your app.xaml and change the `Margin="0,6,0,4"` to match your preferences.

Comment: This is probably the most acceptable solution and the most standard way to go about changing the apperance of any control beyond what levers are offered through the exposed properties so I'm accepting it. In my case I'm embedding WPF controls in a WinForms app through use of ElementHost so the concept of app.xaml doesn't apply. Also as another note, one way that I found around this without modifying the underlying control template is basically to set negative margins on the Separator control itself or through a style.

Answer (score 2):

I always use negative margin: `<Separator Margin="0,-4" />`.

**Edit 2022-03-15:** Does not work anymore since Windows 10 came out.

Comment: You can hardly come up with sth easier than this. Thx